# Pandas Group By Expected Str Instance, Float Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                     everything     file_names  searched_for_found  file_id_value
0      <package_name = 'a.dtsx'         a.dtsx               where              0   
6         'test all the things'         a.dtsx               where              1
12                      'where'         a.dtsx               where              2
18              'group by eggs'         a.dtsx               where              3
24              'order by name'         a.dtsx               where              4
30          where col = 'thing'         b.dtsx               where              5
36         select col_1, col_2          b.dtsx               where              6
42                  from table          b.dtsx               where              7
52          id_value = '123abc'         b.dtsx               where              8            id_value_2 = '123'
62                      'hello'         b.dtsx               where              9
```

I am running this:

```
df_all_xml_mfiles_tgther = df_all_xml_mfiles.groupby(['file_names', 'searched_for_found'])['everything'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

I am getting this error message:

```
sequence item 2813: expected str instance, float found
```

I am not sure what I did wrong, has anyone encountered this before? From what I can tell, the values that I am doing my group by on are all strings, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have NaN in columns everything, adding `fillna` before `groupby`

```
df_all_xml_mfiles.fillna('').groupby(['file_names', 'searched_for_found'])['everything'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way and more specific to the targeted column is to use `fillna('')` or `dropna()` in agg function:

```
df_all_xml_mfiles.groupby(['file_names', 'searched_for_found'])['everything'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()).reset_index()
```